# Do I collect bags at MEX when flying LHR–MEX–CUN?

Tags: transit, luggage, mex, aeromexico

I'm flying with Aeromexico on a single booking London Heathrow–Mexico City–Cancún. Will I need to collect my bags at Mexico City?

(I'm a UK citizen, if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Mexico City Airport, if you are just connecting to an onwards destination, your baggage would be checked in for it's final destination if it's an international one. Otherwise you will have to collect it and pass through customs.

[image]

However you'll have to check if the airline has any restrictions. You can do that while booking your flight or by calling up customer service or even from their facebook chat bot.

Comment: MEX-CUN is a domestic flight so you would expect that there to be a customs inspection of the baggage at MEX. (i.e., bags will be delivered at MEX.) This is indeed what is noted in paragraph (a) of your graphic.

Comment: @Calchas If your final destination doesn't have customs personnel to do the required process you will need to, else you will go through customs at your final destination. When I have flown international, I have gone through customs at my final destination. But might depend on airlines/airports.

Comment: @DumbCoder It really depends on the country. In most countries, you will go through customs when you first enter your country of destination. In this case, that would be at Mexico City. Domestic flights don't have customs arrangements because most people on them are not international travellers. The main exception to this rule is within Europe (excluding Norway), where because of the EEA it is more practical to have customs at the final destination and to allow domestic and intra-EU visitors to self-declare. Finally you have the complication of domestic flights between international ...

Comment: ... terminals such as in Australia, where you go through customs but are not liable for customs duties if only travelling internally. Oh and also sometimes Turkish domestic flights have a weird customs forwarding arrangement as well. But rule of thumb is, Europe: customs at final destination; elsewhere: customs at first entry.